# Put R under double integral

Tags: subscripts

When I use `$\iint_R f(x,y)dA$` the letter `$R$` is to the right of the double integral sign. How to make it under the sign? This is a simple question but I couldn't find a related question.

Comment: @JouleV I managed to mess up the markdown quoting:-), I'll delete and repost the comment, thanks.

Comment: you are using inline mathematics (`$`) the entire design of the layout for inline math is to make it fit within the normal line spacing of the text in a paragraph so limits move to subscript position, if you need the display style it it best to set it as a math display(`\[...\]`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apart from `JouleV's` nice answer, you can use `\limits` option to typeset the inline with equation with limits under the integral symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\iint\limits_a f(x,y) dA$
\end{document}
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: I'd say that `\iint\limits_R` centers the `R` term far better than `\underset{R}{\iint}` does.

Comment: No upper limit should be used when `\limits` follows a command for multiple integrals. You should also respect the OP’s preference for the differential.

Comment: @egreg I have updated my answer, thanks for the remark. Could you also briefly explain why no upper limit must be used?

Comment: @Raaja Because they’re badly positioned.

Comment: @egreg Huhh, like that ;) thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good idea, but if you want to have it, you can use `\underset`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underset{R}{\iint} f(x,y)dA$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the best choice.

Comment: @egreg Yes, it may not be the best, but it surely is a bad one. I will never write like that in my documents